# Entity Framework 5 with n-Tier Architecture

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, wcf-data-services

I have an application that uses Entity Framework 5 and POCO classes using a code-first approach.

This way I have every database table modeled in a Poco class so that way I can have a better control over the model (instead of EDMX stuff).

The application is working fine, but now I want to add a WCF layer, so it works under a n-tier architecture.

What is the best approach to do this?

I'm very familiar with WCF but with ADO.NET returning Datasets. I was reading that for best performance you can return JSON instead of XML so would like to know from experts if there is any example I can look at on how to implement a WCF Layer using Entity Framework that returns JSON objects to the client and viceversa.

Thanks and appreciate any guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such change, if you create your custom class or use entity framework classes. Only you have to put [DataContract] above the class which needs to be serialized and [DataMember] which needs to be serialized in the service.

For eg.

```
[DataContract]
public class Test
{
   [DataMember]
   public string field1 {get; set;}

   [DataMember]
   public string field2 {get; set;}
}
```

And to create WCF service you just needs to put the below code:

it will be in service interface and you just needs to implement in the class.

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    List<test> GetTest();
```

I hope it will help you. :)

Comment: Thanks, so I could have a separate Project.Models and reference that in my client and in my WCF service project and just add the datacontract and datamember in every property that will be serialized right?

Comment: Great Its working fine.. now I only have a problem when calling the WCF method on the client I have:
Model.User user = clientWCF.ValidateUser("test","test");
If I run that I get an error because the User object type is different from Model.User and is strange because is referencing the same Model. If I use:
var user = clientWCF.ValidateUser("test","test"); I can see whats inside.

Comment: Can you please share the code for the service and also share the model.user. So that i can rectify the issue. :)

Comment: I resolved it, very easy. Just when adding the service reference I had to check reuse types and select the Model class. Thanks a lot